# Машинное обучение (Локализация и классификация)

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, машинное-зрение

Вопрос к ML специалистам. Пишу учебный проект в институте, необходимо распознать проявление студентом интереса к лекции например. Подумал классифицировать по двум классам, по типу отвернулся или смотрит, но после размышлений, параметров по моему мнению гораздо больше. Теперь сам вопрос, существуют ли способы либо готовые сети классифицировать действие объекта и локализовать его на фото либо в видео потоке используя один алгоритм?

UPD: Уточнение: необходимо на фото или в видео потоке определить координаты студента, а также его действие.

Answer (score 0):

YOLOv5 - думаю справится с определением людей (быстрая, выделяет прямоугольниками, много статей с примерами).

MotionBERT, ASMNet - занимаются (в том числе) позами.

Поищите тут https://huggingface.co/search/full-text?q=pose&type=model